# backpack for laravel: how to add a custom action / operation?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I need to add and operation to handle downloading of a file.

How can i create route, and add `setupDownloadOperation` in the right way?

Or must I simply do 'laravel-way' manually adding a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs here cover exactly what you need. Just replace “moderate” with “download” in the naming - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operations

Answer (score 2):

Actually we did this

**First - Create a `setupDownloadRoutes`**

Actually this is called automatically ad boot

```
protected function setupDownloadRoutes($segment, $routeName, $controller)
{
    Route::get($segment. '/{id}/download', [
        'as'        => $routeName . '.download',
        'uses'      => $controller . '@download',
        'operation' => 'download',
    ]);
}
```

**Create the `setupDownloadOperation` function**

It's automatically launched *if found*. If you have nothing to do here you can avoid to create it.

```
protected  function setupDownloadOperation()
{
    ...do things here...
}
```

**Create the `download`  function.**

This is the classic controller action of Laravel

```
protected  function download()
{
    ... do thing as usually in a normal action  ...
}
```

I do not find these procedure documented actually

Comment: Thanks for coming back with the solution @realtebo - actually we do have docs for it here - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operations

Comment: It’s not a bad idea to read the “Operations” docs page - they’re very powerful if you understand them.